# Is it a good idea to have usage of both csv and text files in a python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The program i am working on deals with reading and writing multiple text files. But where there was better to use csv files, i replaced the text files with csv files. Now my program deals with some csv files and some text files.
My question is, it is alright to have both types of files in your program OR should I stick to only one type. I mean, all the files should be of csv type only?

Actually, i opt for this approach because for a single word per line, I was getting undesired result.
The code attached below give a list of lists i.e *[['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5']]* but I want a simple list of strings i.e *['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']*.

```
import csv

def writeFile():
    with open('memes.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
        dataWriter = csv.writer(myfile)
        for i in range(5):
            dataWriter.writerow([i])

writeFile()

with open('memes.csv') as myfile:
    datareader = list(csv.reader(myfile))

print(datareader)
```

Comment: This is a design choice, unless you have more specific requirements to share with us, that's more up to you. This question as stated will attract more opinions than objective good or right answer. Just as a nitty remark: a csv file _is_ a text file. Just with a structure more or less known and agreed on.

Comment: do your data _could_ fit only and always in a csv? Why do you need csv? Why do you need text files?

Comment: @Pac0 where i wanted to get data in the form of dictionaries, i used csv file. But there was a scenario where there was just a single word on each line (I mean in the form of a column), so for that i preferred text files.

Comment: but a text file with one word per line could be interpreted as a csv file as well, with one column, couldn't it?

Comment: So, a csv is a *type of text file* with a more or less well defined structure

Comment: @Pac0 I have edited my post. Please go through it.

Comment: A couple of odd things in your code: (a) Why `newline=''`? That's going to mess up CSV for sure... (b) The variable name `datareader` for a `csv.writer` is confusing. (c) When writing a row, supply all the values for that row at once, not one by one.

Comment: @sabik (a) newline = ' ' will prevent an additional extra line after every line. (b) I forget to change it. (c) I don't want my data to be written in a single row. I want the data to be written in a form of column.

Comment: If you want the data to be written in a single column, then `list(csv.reader(myfile))` returning `[['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5']]` is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, that's in a better shape for a Stack Overflow question with a precise problem statement now. Voting to reopen.